# Memory access violation

Tags: c++

My program is reading, the memory that I don't have the access, I have tried multiple debug statements, but could not find what I am doing wrong. The code is not complete yet as I am finding the access violation.

```
// Program to find the length of the longest repeating sequence in a string.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <map>

void longest_sequence(std::string_view s)
{
    std::map<std::string_view, int> m;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = i; j < s.size(); j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                m["" + s[i]]++;
            }
            else
            {
                auto x = s.substr(i, j);
                m[x]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto& i : m)
    {
        std::cout << i.first << ' ' << i.second << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    std::string s = "aabb";
    longest_sequence(s);
}
```

Output:

```
a 1
aa 1
aab 1
ab 1
abb 1
bb 1
ls\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xstring 2
s\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xstring 2
```

Comment: `auto x = s.substr(i, j); m[x]++;` `substr` i suppose could return `npos`. And you are using that (-1) value as index.

Comment: Did you try valgrind's memcheck? Helped me out most of the times....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have map `m` from `string_view` to integers. `string_view` doesn't own memory. It only refers to one. So `m[""+s[i]] =...` will create a string and then `m` will have a string view pointing to a destroyed string leading to UB.

You also most certainly use `substr` incorrectly. Second parameter is size and not location.

I believe what you wanted to write is:

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
 {
    for (size_t j = i+1; j < s.size(); j++)
    {
            m[s.substr(i, j-i)]++;
    }
 }
```

Edit: on the second thought, I am entirely certain what `m[""+s[i]] =...` actually does but it is 100% wrong.